# How to populate datatables with Id and Text but only show Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable thats initialised like this:

```
<script>
    var selected = Array();
    var dataSet = [];
    var idSet = [];
    var rowItem = "";
    var rowIdItem = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $("#table").DataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "filter":false,
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": " Search"
            },
            "select": {
                "style": 'multi'
            },
            "ordering": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "columns": [
               { "title": "Name"},
            ],
            "responsive": true,
            "processing":true,
        }).columns.adjust()
        .responsive.recalc();
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);

        $("#roleSection").on("click", "#removeRole", function (e) {
            let updatedDataSet = [];
            table.rows(".selected").remove().draw();
            table.rows().every(function (Id,Table,Row) {
                let row = this;
                updatedDataSet.push(row.data())
            });
            dataSet = updatedDataSet;
            return false;
        });

        $(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
            dataSet.push([rowItem]);
            idSet.push([rowIdItem]);
            table.row.add([rowItem]).draw();
            $("#modal").empty();
        });

        $(document).on("submit","#form",function (e) {
            var form_data = new FormData;
            for (var i = 0; i < idSet.length; i++) {
                var row = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "Roles[]").attr("value", idSet[i]);
                $("#form").append(row);
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

At the moment if I populate it, it only shows the name of the item and not the Id.

When I want to add an item to it, I open a modal window that has this code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("submit", "#modal", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectedText = $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoleId) :selected").text();
            var selectedId = $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoleId)").val();
            var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
            form_data.push({ name: "RoleList", value: dataSet });
            form_data.push({ name: "RoleName", value: selectedText});
            console.log($("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoleId) :selected").text());
            console.log($("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoleId)").val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("VerifyRole", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                method: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        rowItem = selectedText;
                        rowIdItem = selectedId;
                        $("#close").trigger("click");
                        return;
                    }
                    $.each(result.errors, function (index, item) {
                        // Get message placeholder
                        var element = $('[data-valmsg-for="' + item.propertyName + '"]');
                        element.empty();
                        // Update message
                        element.append($('<span></span>').text(item.errorMessage));
                        // Update class names
                        element.removeClass('field-validation-valid').addClass('field-validation-error');
                        $('#' + item.propertyName).removeClass('valid').addClass('input-validation-error');
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h2>Add Role</h2>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "modal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId,Model.Roles)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                <a href="#" id="close" class="btn btn-default pull-right" rel="modal:close">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This adds a name to the dataSet array and its id to the idSet array.

But I realized that while I can add the name to my datatable and populate a separate array with the ids, when it comes to removing an item from the table, I have no way of removing the Id from the array and then passing it through. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried [hidden columns](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html) by setting `"visible": false` to ID column? It still part of the `DataTable` and searchable if you not setting `"searchable": false`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. How would I declare the javascript array then?

Comment: Hi @TetsuyaYamamoto, I've managed to implement the hidden column. But how do I then delete it based on the Id when its not visible?

Comment: get the value in javascript? give it a randomID and do a delete based on that value